# Opening multiple activities from recyclerview causes the app to lag

Tags: java, android

My app runs fine without any lag. However I have a recyclerview that opens a new activity containing item's details. So let's say activity A has recyclerview and it opens activity B. If the user opens activity B and performs onBackpressed and repeats this process the whole app starts to lag. Basically the flow of interaction that causes the app to lag is : A ->B ->A -> B ... (if user does this more than 10 times the app becomes almost unusable). I have tried leak canary but it doesn't report any memory leak. Also checking the android profile the only memory that goes up is native memory.

In adapter i have nothing at onBindViewHolder beside the bind method. The on click method is implemented through an interface.

```
public class ElementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsAdapter.ElementsViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;

private ElementsRecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;
private List<Elements> elements;
private List<Elements> filteredElements;

public boolean isSearchRequestFiler = false;

ElementsAdapter(Context context) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public ElementsAdapter.ElementsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    return new ElementsAdapter.ElementsViewHolder(RowElementsBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ElementsAdapter.ElementsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bind(filteredElements.get(position));
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ElementsAdapter.ElementsViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(viewHolder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredElements == null ? 0 : filteredElements.size();
}

Elements getItemAt(int position) {
    return filteredElements.get(position);
}

void setRecyclerItemClickListener(ElementsRecyclerItemClickListener elementClickListener) {
    this.recyclerItemClickListener = recyclerItemClickListener;
}
 void setElements(final List<Elements> elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
    this.filteredElements = elements;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ElementsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    final RowElementsBinding binding;

    ElementsViewHolder(RowElementsBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
        this.binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bind(Element element) {
        binding.setElement(element);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (recyclerItemClickListener != null)
            recyclerItemClickListener.onElementClickListener(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

The on Click listener at activity A:

```
@Override
public void onElementClickListener(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("ELEMENTS_ID", adapter.getItemAt(position).getId());
    intent.putExtra("ELEMENTS_OPENED_FROM", "ACTIVITY_A");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why did you put the onElementClickListener in an activity? Why not the adapter itself?

Comment: @npk i do have some other conditions at clicklistener that are easier to calculate on activity before i startActivity which are irrelevant (for this case) because if the conditions fails activity b wont open

Comment: make sure that finalize() method inside the activity will be called when you click back on it and then call garbarge collector in android studio profile tab

Comment: @easy_breezy finalize() method is called when i click on back. Also I forced the garbage collector after i clicked on back and it seems okay.  It seems "Alocated" seems to go higher till garbage collector is not called. This happened if i leave the app open and wont interact with it. Also something that I forgot to mention is that if i refresh activity by calling finish and startActivity(getIntent()) at ActivityA this issue is resolved.

Comment: May be the problem is with your activityB? May be it's onCreate mwthod is the one responsible for being slow?

Comment: @npk activityB isn't lagging. ActivityA is lagging when returned from activityB

Comment: Oh sorry, can you put the code of activityB here?

Comment: @npk ActivityB is a long one because it has two recyclerviews but i dont think the problem is there. I replaced activityB with a blank activity and the app still laggs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many things and doing lots of test I figured out that the reason the lag is happening is facebook sdk (To resolve this I downgraded from 5.0.0. to 4.41.0) . So the facebook sends codeless events and they are allocated in memory and not released until, in my case, Activity A is finished. Hope this helps somebody.